# How to copy selected text from browser?

Tags: android

**Scenario**: I am trying to copy selected text from a browser.

I am using a Service to monitor any kind of copy event.

```
ClipboardManager clipBoard;
CharSequence pasteData = "";


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener( new ClipboardListener() );

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


  if ((clipBoard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType("text/plain"))) {
            //since the clipboard contains plain text.
            ClipData.Item item = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
            // Gets the clipboard as text.
            pasteData = item.getText();


            Toast.makeText(PasteItService.this,
                    pasteData,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PasteItService.this,
                    "Empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

The above code works in other applications like Whatsapp, hike but when I try to copy any selected text or use direct Copy Link Text options in any browser like Chrome or default browser, the above code malfunctions. Some times it successfully shows the toast of the actual text I selected but some times the else part is fired first. Some times the code doesn't works at all. I tried debugging too and get the same result as in toasts.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The data in the clipboard isn't always text from the browser.  You're assuming it is.  Don't do that.  It can also be an intent or a uri, you need to be able to handle those.  Please read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html

Comment: Please inspect the [CODE](http://pastebin.com/xmNBvhpn), I am getting two toast first is null `URI DETECTED!:` and second as `URI DETECTED!:google`